# ¿Comó enviar correo personalizado con una fecha especifica de envio?

Tags: php, html, php7, phpmailer, mail

necesito ayuda con el envio de correos pero que se envie de acuerdo a la fecha de envío, es decir enviar correos con dos o tres dias de anticipación. Por ejemplo, tengo un formulario donde selecciono al usuario a quien deseo enviar el correo, tambien el asunto y tambien un input donde especifico la fecha de envio del correo.

```
<?php

$correoUsuario = $_POST['student-mail'];

$subject = $_POST['subject-mail'];

$to = $correoUsuario;

$email = 'solanoluisangel6@gmail.com';

$fecha = $_POST['date-mail'];

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    if(!empty($to)) {
        
        $checked_contador = count($to);

        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting( E_ALL );

        foreach($to as $seleccion) {
    
            $mensaje = '<p>Hola este es una prueba de mensaje</p>';

            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

            $headers .= "From: <$email>" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Date: ".date("r", strtotime($fecha))." \r\n";
            $headers .= "Cc: $seleccion" . "\r\n";

            $sendMail = mail($seleccion, $subject, $mensaje, $headers);
            
            if (isset($sendMail) ) {
                //echo $headers;
                header("Location: prueba.php?success=Mensaje enviado exitosamente.");
            } else {
                header("Location: prueba.php?error=Hubo un error al enviar el mensaje.");
            } 
        }
    }
    else{
        header("Location: prueba.php?error=Por favor seleccione al menos una opción..");
    }
}
```

?>

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Correos electronicos masivos - Fecha de envio</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="">Seleccione un correo:</label>
        <select name="student-mail[]" id="">
            <option value="solanoluisangel6@gmail.com">Luis Solano</option>
            <option value="riveraluisangel1997@gmail.com">Angel Rivera</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="">Asunto: </label>
        <input type="text" name="subject-mail">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="">Fecha de Envio:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date-mail">

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="boton">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje" name="enviar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Les agredeseria mucho su ayudo, lo que trato de hacer es un reminders con su respectivo fecha de envio o que se envie automaticamente, de acuerdo a la fecha del curso.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta arreglando el codigo que ha quedado fuera del bloque de código y camufla los correos gmail.com que has puesto si no quieres que reciban spam.

Comment: En cuanto a tu problema, con lo que has puesto lo envias de immediato.  Debes repensarte como hacerlo. Mi consejo es que almacenes el contenido del email, los destinatarios y la fecha de envio en una base de datos justo cuando rellenas el formulario, y aparte de eso crear un script en php que corra cada x minutos o x horas o una vez al dia, via cron, que lea la base de datos comprobando sus registros y mirando si el campo fecha_prevista coincide con la fecha actual, y si es así entonces ejecutar el envio.